# not showing value returned from database

Tags: php, mysql, html

i am getting sum of of a certain column from a table, query is right but when i am trying to show that in a table it prints zero. following is my DAO

```
public function getTotal_paid($id)
{
    $dbHandler = new dbConfig();
    $query="select SUM(payed) from itemsale where custId = $id";
    $results = $dbHandler->Query($query);
    return $results;
} // End-Function
```

Following is my logic

```
public function getTotal_paid($id)
{
    $objDAO = new itemsaleDAO();
    $results = $objDAO->getTotal_paid($id);
    return $results;
} // End-Function
```

Here is my front end page

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" align="right">
<tr><th style="height:10px" class="heading_text">Total Paid</th><th style="height:10px    width:10px" class="heading_text">Total Remaining</th></tr>
<?
include_once($commonLocation.'Logic/itemSaleLogic.php'); 
$var= new itemSale();
$object= new itemSaleLogic();
$object1= array();
$object1[0]= new stdClass;
$object1[0]->custId = $_GET['id'];
$var->payed=$object->getTotal_paid($object1[0]);
//$var->remaining=$object->getTotal_rem(6);
echo $var->payed;

echo "<tr><td class=\"inner_text\">".$var->payed."</td>";
//echo "<td class=\"inner_text\">".$var->remaining."</td></tr>";
?>
</table>
```

the object $var->payed is showing zero(ignore spellings of paid)

Comment: dude, you can't have 2 functions with the same name (getTotal_paid)

Comment: @Tom - He can if they're in separate classes, which they likely are, otherwise PHP would throw a parse error.

Comment: does you 2nd function live inside the class? cant make sense of how you are approaching from your examples. you know you have hard coded 6 as an id in your front end page?

Comment: Try `var_dump($dbHandler->Query($query)); is the result a recordset? is a query handle Resource? or whatever? what does dbConfig->Query()?

Comment: i have a folder Models where all the db work is done thats the DAO part(the first total_paid function), it returns to the logic folder(the second function) n then to the front end layer. u can say its 3 layer the logic part is just a wrapper type

Comment: why not make your DB object available to your 2nd class? surely that would be a better approach? then just call your getTotal_paid($id) in the 2nd class

Comment: please ignore the first two things, error is somewhere in the third part, i have a table which deals with item sales, its returning the sum of all the money he has paid for multiple orders. i am not sure what it is returning. an object, a value, or an array.. not sure how to display that sum in the third part

Comment: look at my answer below, note the Query...

Answer (score 0):

Would this not streamline it? seems like you are hopping around classes in an odd way. Not checked or tested, but as an example of how it might be improved:

class itemsale:

```
public function getTotal_paid($id)
{
    global $dbHandler;    // important! this pulls your DB object in..

    $query="select SUM(payed) as itemSum from itemsale where custId = $id";   // note query change here!

    $results = $dbHandler->Query($query);

    return $results;
}
```

front end page

```
include_once($commonLocation.'Logic/itemSaleLogic.php'); 

$dbHandler = new dbConfig();  // make sure you have your DB object...

$var= new itemSale();

$var->getTotal_paid(intval($_GET['id']));

var_dump($var);    // for debug

echo $var->itemSum;  // to output your sum.. do with what you want!


?>
```

Comment: what does var_dump($var) does?

Comment: you need to learn var_dump()...... it will output the contents of your objects/arrays so you can de-bug and figure out whats going on!

Comment: try adding var_dump() to your current script and paste here the dump data so we can see.... your data is going to be in there somewhere, but pretty sure your query needs attention too